# Narrow nested `Record` type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

My types must be driven by server-side data that looks like this

```
const permissionOptions = [
  'read:workspace',
  'create:bot',
  'create:invitation',
  'delete:bot',
] as const
```

My goal is to reduce that data into a `Result` object that looks like this

```
type Result = {
    read: {
        workspace: Boolean
    },
    create: {
        bot: Boolean,
        invitation: Boolean,
    },
    delete: {
        bot: Boolean
    }
}
```

Here's what I have so far
([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=68&pln=9&pc=74#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgUwE4FsCWEJvAeTlbSGAXhgG0BYAKBhgHIkEBDAEwC4B3EJAawjibAEdADTVadYIyZQEbAEYgoo8fSnNZbNGABuaKDMIqa9FggA2CTYuViqAXRhMIMUJCjVqUAJ6IYABWR0TEIAZSgkbQBzEhgfRBAAM3ggjCxcfEIIMjAAVxR5ZHsvXwQYAFUwQgBBYAJwCAAeABUYBAAPWTAWF2hIsCiAPljWjq6emAADABIAb21E5Bha+rAAXzY5vui1yZgAfmW6whg2GDAEHWQSv0rCAGkEbybqts6Ebpd-EBD5SxWsiIYKN3p8YNsBsNSCDxi4ZrNqhs5gslo9vLsDjA0adzpdrlQbmVvr9-scGrE7uAAQ1GoFUGkwhFooNCQEflg-gg0S5SJSwNzaey0JzqZAgXTgukwOF+kNPFR4mUAEoICC5cywUgq0BIFiCkkIUUQIHa7h64kcyzcoGKECWJhgQYsglURK5MBksBxVVQAAUSDOKrVGoAlGcdCA0CwYLNVLQkAA6aQsBM2GAAenTMGT4IAFiB1dHwOZvDBc0wrlMuLx+IIEJM49mE+oZAgE9W+AIhBmsy3ZHmC+Yi2AS2WK2U6DY6DAAD70bR6AyrOjUNZAA))

```
type PermissionString = typeof permissionOptions[number]
type UnionActions<T extends string> = T extends `${infer Action}:${string}` ? Action : never
type UnionKeys<A extends PossibleActions, T extends string> = T extends `${A}:${infer Key}` ? Key : never

type PossibleActions = UnionActions<PermissionString>
type PossibleKeys = UnionKeys<PossibleActions, PermissionString>

type Result = Record<PossibleActions, Record<PossibleKeys, boolean>>

function test(r: Result): void {
    r.read.bot // read should only have `workspace`
    r.create.workspace // create should only have 'bot' | 'invitation'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, thanks to [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)

```
type Result = {[A in PossibleActions]: Record<UnionKeys<A, PossibleKeys>, Boolean>}
```

([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgUwE4FsCWEJvAeTlbSGAXhgG0BYAKBhgHIkEBDAEwC4B3EJAawjibAEdADTVadYIyZQEbAEYgoo8fSnNZbNGABuaKDMIqa9FggA2CTYuViqAXRhMIMUJCjVqUAJ6IYABWR0TEIAZSgkbQBzEhgfRBAAM3ggjCxcfEIIMjAAVxR5ZHsvXwQYAFUwQgBBYAJwCAAeABUYBAAPWTAWF2hIsCiAPljWjq6emAADABIAb21E5Bha%20rAAXzY5vui1yZgAfmW6whg2GDAEHWQSv0rCAGkEbybqts6Ebpd-EBD5SxWsiIYKN3p8YNsBsNSCDxi4ZrNqhs5gslo9vLsDjA0adzpdrlQbmVvr9-scGrE7uAAQ1GoFUGkwhFooNCQEflg-gg0S5SJSwNzaey0JzqZAgXTgukwOF%20kNPFR4mUAEoICC5cywUizMivbRskkIUUQexnFWgJAsRp8gXVcVCzncwZAgBCIBAliYYEGa3liVyYDJYDiqqgAAokKbVeqoABKM46EBoFgwWaqWhIAB00hYGZsMAA9PmYNnwQALEDq5PgczeGClphXKZcXj8QQISZp4sZ9QyBAZ5t8ARCAtFnuyMsV8xVsA1usNsp0Gx0GAAH3o2j0BlWdGoayAA))